# WaitExten() problem to identify typed numbers

Tags: asterisk

I'm having constant problems with the function WaitExten().
Our customers are having problems to type a sequence of numbers, this function doen´t identify them all.
It depends on the phone device used, the speed typed, but in general, it fails in most part.
Is there some sensibility adjustment or something I can set to increase the recognition ratio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not problem of WaitExten

It is problem of dtmf recognition from thoose devices.

If devices are native-sip(not analog), you can change dtmf mode to any other except inband, that will help 100%.

If devices related to pstn,gsm or analog telephony, you can try play with radio-relax flags(at compilation time) or with digit length on device.